# Ruby unknown + on trying to join 2 strings

Tags: ruby, string

So, I'm learning Ruby and immediately, have stumbled upon something rater peculiar when trying to concatenate 2 strings to one. Here's the code, with irrevelant parts stripped, lets just say Sinatra runs it:

```
class CMS
    # Set the site path root.
    @sitePath = "./site"

    get '/' do
        renderCache = File.readlines(@sitePath + "index.liquid")
    end
end
```

And on loading the page, I am greeted with

```
NoMethodError at /
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

on the `renderCache = File.readlines(@sitePath + "index.liquid")` line. Why is it refusing to concatenate the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set instance variables at the class level. You need to set them in an instance method.

Look's like you're using sinatra so you can do this:

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16117807/2981429) for how to make a "before filter" like one does in Rails apps. This solution is for the *modular* style of Sinatra app.

To show an example:

```
class CMS < Sinatra::Base
  before do
    @sitePath = "./site"
  end
  get '/' do
    renderCache = File.readlines(@sitePath + "index.liquid")
  end
end
CMS.run!
```

You could also keep your existing code if you use a constant instead of an instance variable:

```
class CMS
    # Set the site path root.
    SitePath = "./site"

    get '/' do
        renderCache = File.readlines(CMS::SitePath + "index.liquid")
    end
end
```

To explain how I read your error and looked for the error:

`undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass` means you're calling `+` on something which is nil. Referencing the code shows that the nil variable is `@sitePath`. Undefined instance variables will evaluate to `nil`. This is different than standard variables, which will raise an undefined variable error.

Comment: The recommendation to use the namespace is much better. Worth noting that Ruby tradition holds that constants are specified like `SITE_PATH`, plus given the context here, `CMS::` is implied and can be omitted.